# Jackson map special character to null

Tags: java, jackson

How to configure Jackson json deserializer such that special characters say "##", "#null", "-" to null

For example:
    Say my json is

```
{ "userId":"kp","fname":"k","lname":"p","mname":"##", rndNum:"-"}
```

And Java class is

```
class User{
    private String userId;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String mname;
    private Integer rndNum;

    //getters/ and setters
}
```

I would expect output to be

```
user.getUserId() = kp
user.getMname() = null
user.getRndNum() = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a constructor and a validator for that. e.g.

```
public static String validate(String name) {
    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty() && (name.charAt(0) == '#' || name.charAt(0) == '-')) {
        return null;
    }
    return name;
}

class User {
    User(String userId, String fname, String lname, String mname) {
        this.userId = validate(userId);
        this.fname = validate(fname);
        this.lname = validate(lname);
        this.mname = validate(mname);
    }
```

I also think this properly separates functionality. Jackson code and annotations should handle deserialization of whatever happens to be in the JSON. Your class should know if values used for initialization is valid regardless where they come from.

Comment: I added one more scenario, where integer is null character. Does Jackson call constructors to initialize fields?

Comment: If class `User` has non-primitive fields these are constructed either in `User` constructor, or in respective setters or directly if they are public. Jackson can use any of these. If you go with the above approach you will need a validator for `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this depending on how advanced solution you need:

- [There](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) is an easy way if you are willing to register your types one-by-one. In this solution you are providing the deserialization code from raw Jackson objects to your desired output.
- Or you can go with the more powerful solution which overrides the default Serializer by using a [custom provider](https://hussainpithawala.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/overriding-default-serializationdeserialization-behaviour-of-jackson-json-serializer/) to cover all types. Here you are defining how Strings should be deserialized in general.